# Xpages type ahead functionality don't work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, xpages, type-ahead

I developed a web form in Xpages with functionality "type ahead" for a field. Works perfectly in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE 7, IE 8, but does not work in IE 9. When I start typing in the field with the function should show a list of data for selection based on the first typed characters, but in IE 9 will not appear on this list. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Which Domino version do you use? Because IE9 is officially not supported in Dojo 1.4.3, who is been used by Domino 8.5.2.
See comment in OpenNTF project defect, [ExtLib - Bug In IE9 Popups](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/response.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=70209D816663E7FE8625799700311C2F&MainID=B9FE584BD9B5A1A48625798E0069C9F8)

Comment: Here we are using Domino version 8.5.2, then the problem is really compatibility. Its possible to install version 1.6 of Dojo in Domino 8.5.2, or I have to upgrade to Domino 8.5.3 and update the version of Dojo?

Comment: While it is possible to update the version of Dojo on the Domino 8.5.2 server it is a lot of work and will not be supported by IBM. The best bet is to upgrade to 8.5.3 so you continue to have a supported environment.

Comment: I have a SPR at IBM about the popup.js in Dojo 1.4.3 is not compatible with IE9. So maybe they will fix the IE9 compability in 8.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Dojo 1.6.1 on a Domino 8.5.2 server.  It solved a number of minor problems, including letting me run a database built with the discussionXL template.  I only needed to copy the dojo-1.6.1 folder from 8.5.3 install to 8.5.2 server.